# How are values such as monthly cost stored in a data warehouse

Tags: data-warehouse

Would a value such as monthly cost from source data be represented as a fact?
If yes, how would a date dimension table be designed around that fact?

Comment: No, I don't think so.  According to ["What is a fact table,"](http://searchdatamanagement.techtarget.com/definition/fact-table), a fact  corresponds to a single event, like a sale.  Monthly Cost would be either part of a rollup in a report, or part of a rollup table in an OLAP database.

Comment: Thanks Robert, in that case the dataset for monthly cost can be added as a dimension in the warehouse? The source data is like a cost schedule, so I have - ID,Product Family, Product Name, Monthly Cost

Comment: Possibly.  It depends on how you've set up your warehouse.